# can't run ubuntu after installing windows 8

Tags: 12.04

i have **ubuntu** 12.04 and it work with me very well.
i want to re-install Windows 8 and now i can't open ubuntu or boot on it what can i do please help me ??
i am tring to use apps on windows to make my partion that i installed ubuntu on it and it don't work.
and if i can't run it again if there any way to restore my apps and my files on the desktop :/
and if there any way to restore ubuntu with losing Windows i will do it .

Answer (score 1):

Windows has overwritten your MBR (Master Boot Record). To recover ubuntu:

1. Using an ubuntu CD or a live usb, boot into a live session
2. Install Boot-Repair `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update`
3. `sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (boot-repair &)`
4. Type in terminal `boot-repair`
5. Click the "Recommended repair" button
6. Reboot ubuntu

For more info, check out [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) page

Comment: I did the same but no help